# Phalcon Router and Loader for subfolder structure getting bigger. How to set up?

Tags: php, url-routing, phalcon

I have a quite big project that I need to program. I used to code with CodeIgniter but since they stopped maintaining the framework, I decided to switch to another. I chose Phalcon framework. The folder structure of the application that I want to implement is next:

- app/

  - controllers/

    - admin/

      - users/

        - UsersController.php
        - UserGroupsController.php
      - dashboard/
      - system/
      - another_subfolder/

        - AnotherSubFolderController.php
    - production/

      - settings/
        SettingsController.php
      - dashboard/
      - flow/
      - another_subfolder/

        - AnotherSubFolderController.php
    - website1/

      - customers/

        - CustomersController.php
        - CompaniesController.php
      - another_subfolder .... /
  - models/

    - sub_folder_structure/ // The same as controllers

This is just example of the folder structure of the application. There will be quite a lot of folders and sub-folders in this project to make it manageable.

From my understanding I need to register all namespaces at the loader for each sub-folder, so that Phalcon knows where to search and load the class.

```
//Register an autoloader
$loader = new \Phalcon\Loader();

$loader->registerNamespaces(array(
// Main
'Controllers' =>'app/controllers/',
'Models' =>'app/models/',
// Admin Routing
'Controllers\Admin'=>'app/controllers/admin',
'Models\Admin'=>'app/models/admin',
'Controllers\Admin'=>'app/controllers/admin',
'Models\Admin'=>'app/models/admin',
'Controllers\Admin\Users'=>'app/controllers/admin/users',
'Models\Admin\Users'=>'app/models/admin/users'

))->register();
```

The loader will look quite big.

Then I have to set-up the router so that requests redirected to the right controller. Right now I have next:

```
// Setup Router
$di->set('router', function(){

     $router = new \Phalcon\Mvc\Router(false);

     $router->removeExtraSlashes(true);

     $router->add('/', array(
        'namespace' => 'Controllers',
        'controller' => "login"
     ));

      $router->add('/:controller/:action/', array(
        'namespace' => 'Controllers',
        'controller' => 1,
        'action' =>2
     ));

      $router->add('/admin/:controller/:action/', array(
        'namespace' => 'Controllers\Admin',
        'controller' => 1,
        'action' =>2
     ));

     $router->add('/admin/users/:controller/:action/', array(
        'namespace' => 'Controllers\Admin\Users',
        'controller' => 1,
        'action' =>2
     ));

     return $router;
});
```

That will be also very big if I need to manually setup router for each sub-folder and namespace.

So the questions that I have are this:

1. Is there any way to make a loader prettier and smaller? As it will grow bigger.
2. How can I setup router so that I don't need to enter all of the namespaces and combinations of subfolders? Is there any way to make it smaller? May be modify dispatcher or any other class? Or is there a way I can set a path variable in the router to the location of the controller?

I have researched Phalcon documentation but could not find the way to do that.

Any help and suggestions are very much appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Did you already read about my efforts for this problem [in this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22673713/741981)? If not, take a look :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ad. 1. You can change your namespaces to be more PSR-0 (in my opinion), so I would make:

- app

  - controllers

    - Admin

      - Users

        - UsersController.php

The you can register one namespace `Admin` or any other. Then you need to register only the top most namespace to work (keep in mind that your `UsersController` must have `namespace Admin\Users\UsersController;` to work). Thena autoloader should have only:

```php
 $loader
    ->registerDirs(
        array(
            // It's taken from my config so path may be different
            __DIR__ . '/../../app/controllers/'
            // other namespaces here (like for models)
        )
    );
```

I'm using `registerDirs` so I only point loader to the folder in which some namespace exists.

Ad. 2.

For this you can use [groups of routes](http://docs.phalconphp.com/en/latest/reference/routing.html#groups-of-routes) so you can pass a namespace as a parameter for config array of constructor and then do the repeative task in one place. Then just create new instances with different parameters;

```php
$router->addGroup(new MahGroup(array('namespace' => 'Mah\\Controller'));
```

So inside MahGroup class could be:

```php
class MahGroup extends Phalcon\Mvc\Router\Group {
    public function _construct($config = array()) {
       $this->setPrefix('/' . $config['perfix']);
       $router->add('/:controller/:action/', array(
          'namespace' => $config['namespace'],
          'controller' => 1,
          'action' => 2
       ));
       // etc...
    }
}
```

And then configuring routes:

```
$router->addGroup( new MahGroup(array('prefix' => 'mah-namespace', 'namespace' => 'Mah\\Namespace' )) );
$router->addGroup( new MahGroup(array('prefix' => 'mah-other-namespace', 'namespace' => 'Mah\\Other\\Namespace' )) );
```

But given examples for second question are just what could be done. I usually create `Group` class for each namespace and then declare some routes that my app uses since I'm not using english names for routes and I need rewriting polish urls to controllers which have also some namespaces.

Comment: If you use `registerDirs` it will check for any namespace in all sub folders? I mean any controller under '/app/controllers/'  will be loaded no matter the namespace?

Comment: Thanks jodator! I understand now about the Loader. It makes sense now. Could you please clarify about routing. Does it still mean that I need to enter all namespaces into the $config to create a $router->addGroup()? I'm a little bit confused. If you could add some code examples, that would be great :)

Comment: @cvsguimaraes Yep I have for instance registered folder 'library' with at least two main namespaces (`library/Namespace1` and `library/Namespace2`).

Comment: @jodator, thanks for clarification and your effort. Now it makes sense :)